# R setting of par for saveVideo

Tags: r, video

I have two stacks of images (each of 256 x 256 and 20 of these images in each stack) and I am making a video file using saveVideo for displaying the images from two stacks side by side, i.e. 512 x 256.

The images appeared to be squeezed in x-axis. I tried a few different combinations, but can't get the ratio right. Any thoughts, please?

```
par(mar = c(5, 0.2, 1, 2), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), tcl = -0.3, cex.axis = 1, cex.lab = 1, cex.main = 1)

ani.options(interval = 0.1, nmax = 50, ani.height=1, ani.width=4)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the aspect ratio to 1? `asp=1`

Comment: @user5219763 I have just tried that and the ratio didn't change. May I just check whether the mar, mgp, ani.height and ani.width should be kept as above? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by adding "-vf scale=512:256" for ffmpeg.